# What is the meaning of kernel in GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

In this code below, what is the meaning of the key `kernel` in the variable parameters?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC

parameters = {'kernel': ('linear', 'rbf'), 'C': (1, 4, 8, 16, 32)}

svc = SVC()
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, cv=5)
clf.fit(train_x_vectors, train_y)
```

Comment: It configures what kernel you want to use. You can read about linear and rbf kernels in the documentation. If you use rbf you should probably also gridsearch sigma, not only C.

Comment: The parameters dictionary specifies the values which the parameters of the classifier will take. So `'kernel'` is not a parameter of `GridSearchCV`, but a parameter of `SVC`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of grid search is to tune the hyperparameters of a given modelling algorithm. In particular, the `GridSearchCV` object needs to know which hyperparameters to vary, and what values to vary them over. That's what the `parameters` dictionary is for. All of the keys in `parameters` must match hyperparameters for the particular algorithm.

In this case, `kernel` and `C` are hyperparameters for the support vector classifier (`SVC`) controlling the type of kernel to use, and the regularization parameter respectively. The `GridSearchCV` machinery is simply passing them on to the model.

Check out [the `SVC` docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) and [the `GridSearchCV` docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)